# Lightning:input type=“date” floating left

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using the lightning:input type="date" to have a datepicker but I can't float the datepicker icon and the calendar on the left of the input. Is there some way to do it even overriding styles?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using styles from Lightning Component Bundle using thins sample code:

```
.THIS .slds-datepicker {
    left : 0px !important;
}
```

There's probably some better way to set component's position but that does the work.

Comment: Yeah, but it moves the calendar on the left of the page, It has to be on the left of the container aligned with the input

Comment: @CarlosIribar could you share your code? It seems to be working in every configuration i tried.